# Prove $f(a)^2\sin(2a)=f(b)^2\sin(2b)$ for every closed curve given by $(f(t)\cos(t),f(t)\sin(t))$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I stumbled upon this question recently, and actually managed to solve it. But, if to be honest - I don't like my solution. It feels too long, not very smart, and it is divided to cases (which is very unpleasant to me). I was wondering if there was a smarter solution to the problem; That's why I came here.

**The Question**:

Let $\gamma\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed, simple and piecewise-smooth planar curve, and let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function. Given $a,b\in\Bbb R$, the parametrization of $\gamma$ is given by:

$$\gamma(t)=(f(t)\cos(t),f(t)\sin(t))\\ t\in[a,b]$$

Prove the following equality:

$$f(a)^2\sin(2a)=f(b)^2\sin(2b)$$

**My Solution**:

Let $k_1,k_2\in\Bbb Z$. We know that $\gamma$ is closed. Thus:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
f(a)\cos(a) &= f(b)\cos(b)\\
f(a)\sin(a) &= f(b)\sin(b)\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

**Case 1**: $f(a)=0$.

If $f(a)=0$, then we get from the system of equations that $f(b)=0$ too (since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are never $0$ for the same value), proving the desired equality.

**Case 2**: $a$ can be given by $a=\pi k_1$. Thus:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
f(a)(-1)^{k_1} &= f(b)\cos(b)\\
0 &= f(b)\sin(b)\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Assuming $f(b)\neq0$, we'll get (according to the second equation) that $\sin(b)=0$. In other words, $b$ can also be given by $b=\pi k_2$. Therefore, $\sin(2a)=\sin(2b)=0$, which proves the desired equality.

**Case 3**: $a$ can be given by $a=\frac \pi 2+\pi k_1$. Thus:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
0 &= f(b)\cos(b)\\
f(a)(-1)^{k_1} &= f(b)\sin(b)\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

This case is very similar to the previous one: we'll assume again that $f(b)\neq0$, and then we'll get from the first equation that $b$ can be given by $b=\frac \pi 2+\pi k_2$, implying again that $\sin(2a)=\sin(2b)=0$, which proves the desired equality.

$(*)$ For cases 1,2 and 3, we have symmetry between $a$ and $b$, of course. Thus, choosing the inital condition on $b$ (rather than on $a$ as we did) won't change the solution.

**Case 4:** All other options:

For all the other options, we will get that *neither* of the elements in the system of equations can be $0$. Thus, we can divide one equation by the other and get:

$$\tan(a)=\tan(b)\implies a=b+\pi k_1$$

Plugging this equality to one of the equations, we will get:

$$f(a)(-1)^{k_1}\cos(b)=f(b)\cos(b)$$

And since $\cos(b)\neq0$:

$$f(a)(-1)^{k_1}=f(b)\implies f(a)^2=f(b)^2\tag{1}$$

Also, note that:

$$\sin(2a)=\sin(2b+2\pi k_1)=\sin(2b)\tag{2}$$

Multiplying equation $(1)$ by $(2)$, we will get the desired equation. $\blacksquare$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases}
f(a)\cos(a) = f(b)\cos(b)\\
f(a)\sin(a) = f(b)\sin(b)
\end{cases}$$ because $\gamma$ is closed. Multiplying side by side
$$ f(a)^2\cos(a)\sin(a)=f(b)^2\cos(b)\sin(b)$$ Multiplying  now by $2$ one has $$ f(a)^2\sin(2a)=f(b)^2\sin(2b)$$

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was allowed to multiply side by side, since things might be zero

Comment: If they are zero then the equality of your statement is equal to zero as well